# I cannot access the profiler in Pycharm 3.4

Tags: pycharm, profile

I am using Pycharm 3.4 and I want to profile the code. The documentation says:

> Choose Run | Profile  on the
>   main menu.

But when I try that I see no Profile option in the run menu.

As you might expect, I googled heavily. Its hard to come up with anything but PyCharm docs that don't mention the problem. I have also searched the pycharm forum to no avail. There are some posts on stack overflow but they don't mention this problem.

Kind of a basic thing! But I don't know how to proceed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the professional edition:
https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

> Supported only  in Professional Edition
>
> Cython Django AppEngine Flask Jinja2 Mako web2py Pyramid Profiler
>   SQLAlchemy Diagrams Remote interpreters, remote debugging, Vagrant,
>   Docker Duplicate code detection Code coverage .po files support BDD
>   support Profiler integration Thread Concurrency Visualization

Here is a [great alternative](http://softwaretester.info/python-profiling-with-pycharm-community-edition/).